# How to import an FBX file into Blender

Tags: import, unity

I am trying to import an FBX file from Unity into Blender. Does anybody know how to do that?

Comment: _File > Import > Autodesk FBX (.fbx)_?

Comment: What do you mean by "from Unity?" How is Unity producing the FBX file?

Comment: This question is probably voted down because FBX is in the import menu, if you wanted to know more details about the format support relating to unity, you should ask them in your question. I think its expected that if you ask a question you already made some attempt to perform the task first.

Comment: Actually, even though this is a super obvious question, I've noticed that it's getting lots of views because this is probably a common search term. I changed my initial downvote into an upvote and I'd suggest one more person give an upvote to neutralize the question. It may be a basic question, but it's also a useful one.

Comment: @Keavon I removed my DV, however this does not deserve a positive score. An upvote is to be used when a question "shows research effort; is useful and clear"

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I completely agree, but I feel it should have a neutral score (0).

Comment: @Keavon Exactly, I removed my DV for that express purpose. Someone else DV'd it.

Comment: I love how everyone says import. It would help to know what version of FBX Blender uses.

Answer (score 24):

*File* > *Import* > *FBX (.fbx)*

Then browse for the file on the next screen, select it, and click *Import FBX*. The model should then be loaded into the scene.

[image: File > Import > FBX (.fbx)*]

If you can't find the option to import FBX files in the file menu, you may need to activate the addon. Go to *User Preferences > Add-ons* then search for "fbx" and activate the relevant extension.

Comment: I import on v2.76b, but it doesnt import textures and bone weights? then I can open on v2.83.12. Wonder if there is a good importer somewhere.